# How does asp.net 4.0 set form action on web forms. puzzling results

Tags: .net, webforms, asp.net-4.0

Does anyone know how asp.net 4.0 sets the value of the **action** attribute of a web form.  I ran into a situation where the action attribute does not have the correct value when the url contains a "/" after the page name.

For example, take the url **localhost/test/Default.aspx**

After page loads, when looking at the page source in the browser, the action attribute looks like **action="Default.aspx"**, which is expected.

Now, take the same url, but add a / after the page name and some text, like, **localhost/test/Default.aspx/www.xyz.com**

After page loads, when looking at the page source in the browser, the action attribute looks like **action="www.xyz.com"**. As you can see, the value of the action attribute is whatever was entered after the /.

Has anyone run into this?  This only happens with asp.net 4.0 apps.  When doing the same test on an asp.net 2.0 app, the action attribute is always **Default.aspx**

I haven't been able to find an explanation of this behavior, and what can be done to eliminate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a default behaviour of ASP.NET.

Looking at the GetActionAttribute() code of the HtmlForm class (via decompilation tool) it takes whatever exists after the last / and sets it as a value of the action attribute.

One way to override this is to set the RenderingCompatibility of the form to:

this.form1.RenderingCompatibility = new Version(4, 5);

When it sees this, it will set the action attribute to ./